# how to initialize an array of struct dynamically in c

Tags: c

now what I want to do is to return a pointer pointing to an array of struct in the function findP, my code is in the following:

```
typedef struct Pair Pair;
struct Pair {
    long long first;
    long long snd;
};
Pair constStr(long long first, long long snd)
{
    Pair pair;
    pair.first = first;
    pair.snd = snd;
    return pair;
}

Pair** findP(long long n) 
{
    int len = 0;
    struct Pair iPair[100];

    for (long long i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (long long j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (i * j + i + j == (n * n + n) / 2 && i != j)
            {
                Pair p = constStr(i, j);
                iPair[len] = p;
                len++;

            }
        }
    }

    Pair** iPPtr = malloc(len * sizeof(Pair*));
    iPPtr = iPair;   
    if (len > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {            
            iPPtr[i] = &iPair[i];
            printf("first %d and second %d.", iPPtr[i]->first, iPPtr[i]->snd);
        }
    }
    return iPPtr;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to firstly create an array of struct iPair containing "len" structs (len is calculated based on the input n) and pass it to Pair** iPPtr. The result, in the case that n = 26, shall be that len = 2, the first struct created in iPair shall be P1.first = 15, P1.snd = 21 and the 2nd struct p2.first = 21, p2.snd =15. However after passing to iPPtr, the first value of the first struct becomes something like an address (e.g. p1.first = 1842452398400). Anybody could give me a hint on why is that? why the first value of the first struct becomes that during passing to the Pair** type? Thanks!

Comment: `iPPtr[i] = &iPair[i];` The variable `struct Pair iPair[100];` is local to the function, it stops existing after function returns. Just instead of allocating `len` pointers to Pairs, allocate `len` Pairs.

Comment: `malloc(len*  sizeof(Pair))`.